# Create a dictionary from lists, overwrite duplicate keys

Tags: python

I have my code below. I am trying to create a dictionary from my lists extracted from a txt file but the loop overwrites the previous information:

```
f = open('data.txt','r')
lines = f.readlines()
lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('data.txt')]
columns=lines.pop(0)

for i in range(len(lines)):
    lines[i]=lines[i].split(',')

dictt={}
for line in lines:
    dictt[line[0]]=line[1:]

print('\n')
print(lines)
print('\n')
print(dictt)
```

I know I have to play with:

```
for line in lines:
    dictt[line[0]] = line[1:]
```

part but what can I do , do I have to use `numpy`? If so, how?

My `lines` list is :

```
[['USS-Enterprise', '6', '6', '6', '6', '6'],
['USS-Voyager', '2', '3', '0', '4', '1'],
['USS-Peres', '10', '4', '0', '0', '5'],
['USS-Pathfinder', '2', '0', '0', '1', '2'],
['USS-Enterprise', '2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
['USS-Voyager', '2', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
['USS-Peres', '8', '5', '0', '0', '4'],
['USS-Pathfinder', '4', '0', '0', '2', '1']]
```

My dict becomes:

```
{'USS-Enterprise': ['2', '2', '2', '2', '2'],
'USS-Voyager': ['2', '1', '0', '1', '1'],
'USS-Peres': ['8', '5', '0', '0', '4'],
'USS-Pathfinder': ['4', '0', '0', '2', '1']}
```

taking only the last ones, I want to add the values together. I am really confused.

Comment: Consider using the [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/) library

Comment: A dictionary cannot have duplicate keys

Comment: I tried this now, I get error, dictt[line[0]]=dictt[line[0]]+line[1:] maybe if i add it onto it it'd change. I'm also tired so I need some help understanding. Thank you.

Comment: @sshashank124 I can not use the pandas library. I mean I can but the orders are to do it without using any libraries.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer What do you mean ?

Comment: `['USS-Peres', '10', '4', '0', '0', '5']` gets overwritten by `['USS-Peres', '8', '5', '0', '0', '4']`

Comment: @AyberkKum, do you need an appended list as the value of the dictionary? Otherwise the values may be overwritten

Comment: The input is not a dictionary, it's a CSV file. The first element is a string index. Not a key. Just use `pandas.read_csv()` to read it.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: You subsequently clarified in comments that your input has duplicate keys, and you want later rows to overwrite earlier ones.

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER: The input is not a dictionary, it's a CSV file. Just use `pandas.read_csv()` to read it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('my.csv', sep='\s+', header=None)

df
                0   1  2  3  4  5
0  USS-Enterprise   6  6  6  6  6
1     USS-Voyager   2  3  0  4  1
2       USS-Peres  10  4  0  0  5
3  USS-Pathfinder   2  0  0  1  2
4  USS-Enterprise   2  2  2  2  2
5     USS-Voyager   2  1  0  1  1
6       USS-Peres   8  5  0  0  4
7  USS-Pathfinder   4  0  0  2  1
```

Seems your input didn't have a header row. If your input columns had names, you can add them with `df.columns = ['Ship', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']` or whatever.

If you really want to write a dict output (beware of duplicate keys being suppressed), see `df.to_dict()`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to append multiple values for the same key. You can use defaultdict for that, or modify your code and utilize the `get` method for dictionaries.

```
for line in lines:
    dictt[line[0]] = dictt.get(line[0], []).extend(line[1:])
```

This will look for each key, assign the `line[1:]` if the key is unique, and if it is duplicate, simply append those values onto the previous values.

Answer (score 0):

```
dict_output = {}
for line in list_input:
    if line[0] not in dict_output:
        dict_output[line[0]] = line[1:]
    else:
        dict_output[line[0]] += line[1:]
```